# Similar program to Team Foundation Server

Tags: git, svn, version-control, tfs

we are 3 programmers that work via internet. The mayor problem that we have is that we often overwrite each other files.
What we are looking for is a program that block files for editing. For example, when I want to edit the file, I want the program to download the lastest version of that file and block it to prevent other users overwrite it, when I'm done editing that file, the program should upload to the server and unblock it so anyone else could edit it.
The version control is a desirable feature but not necessary.

We need that this can run over a regular server (any cheap hosting with a MYSQL database).

We test Git and Subversion but we have difficulties to understand (if they even can) how they run over a regular hosting service.

Any advice or solution is welcome.

Comment: Please note that Git—by its decentralised nature—is unable to lock files and prevent other users from editing them. Subversion does have the ability to lock files.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [GitHub](https://github.com/plans) for a hosted Git repository. Their plan is very cheap, only $7 per month for 5 private projects.

Team Foundation Services (as mentioned by Nockawa) are great as well, with pricing from $5 per user and 5 free users per account. There is a workgroup edition for TFS (up to 5 users) which comes with an MSDN subscription. You can run that from anywhere.

As for other hosting solutions, there's multiple vendors out there that can host Subversion or Git or plain old CVS or Mercurial for you. Samples:

- http://codesion.com/
- https://github.com/plans
- http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/team-foundation-server/hosting
- https://bitbucket.org/
- https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/MercurialHosting

In the end I'd choose a hosting provider that provides Source control as a service. I wouldn't look for a web provider where you can install your own version of a source control product. It's much easier to maintain and they will take the burden of optimizing and back-upping for you.

As for the blocking issue, exclusively locking is 'old style'. Instead most source control systems, TFS included, provide a way to merge your changes and will flag that the file was changed since you last grabbed the latest version. Merging is very powerful and it helps you work together smoother once you get the hang of it.

Comment: Microsoft has added Git support to Team Foundation Service as well. You can now choose that as your default source control system when creating a new team project.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [TFSPreview](http://tfspreview.com/) to use a TFS server on the cloud. To answer the "blocking file" issue, configure the Team Project's Source Control settings to use [Exclusive Checkout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms242869.aspx) by clearing the Enable multiple checkout checkbox.

For now TFSPreview is free but Microsoft always said their goal is not the make money from it, so expect a pretty damn good level of service for the price you'll pay and no worries about the setup & maintenance.